# ng-show does not work if referenced property is created by directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-show, generated

I have an form with an text input and a validation message that has to be shown if the input changes. (This example make no sence but it is reduced to the base problem)
What I want to generate in my angularJS directive is:

```
<p>Username:<br> 
  <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required> 
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty"> Username is dirty.</span>
</p>
```

See the example here. (The static passwd code works, the generated user code not)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCrtl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = 'MyName';
    $scope.passwd = 'MyPw';
})
.directive("mytest", function($compile){
        return{
      scope: true,
            link: function(scope, element){
                var template = '<input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>'+
'<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty">'+
'Username is dirty.</span>';
                var tmpFn= $compile(template);
                var content = tmpFn(scope);
                element.append(content);
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>  
<body>

<h2>Validation</h2>

<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCrtl" 
name="myForm" novalidate>

<!-- the generated code does not work -->
<p mytest>User:<br>
</p>

<!-- the static code works-->
<p>Password:<br>
<input type="text" name="passwd" ng-model="passwd" required>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.passwd.$dirty">
Password is dirty.</span>
</p>  
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

The problem seems, that myForm.user is created in the directive

Comment: The problem most probably is that when compiling the `<input>` it does not know about its parent form to register itself, so the form does *NOT* get a `user` property. Do you really need to compile the template manually? (My guess from what I am seeing is *NO*!)

Comment: As I wrote, the example above is reduced to the main problem. I want to define a directive that creates one line of my form (label, input, validation, in case of enums a select list...) Today I am coping a lot of code for over 20 lines in my form. My "dream" is to have sth like <div myFormElement="User" myValMessage="Please select a user" myEnumSource="Users"...></div>

Answer (score 0):

Remove scope: true so your directive doesn't create new scope and set priority. If that don't work try with this directive

```
function dynamicName($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        priority: 1000,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var name = scope.$eval(attrs.dynamicName);
            if (name) {
                element.attr('name', name);
                element.removeAttr('dynamic-name');
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

use like this

```
<input dynamic-name="inputName">
```